# Oracle Apex pass item value from one page to another

Tags: oracle-apex

I am just looking into Apex and have set up two pages:
- one with an entry text box called SEARCH_STRING;
- the second page is a report based on the entry made the first page with a field called P2_X.
I want to pass the value of the string to the second page but it does not appear.

On the first page, I have configured the button so it will set P2_X with SEARCH_STRING, (actually listed as &SEARCH_STRING) but whatever text I type in, nothing appears in P2_X.

This is such a straightforward operation, I know I'm missing something fundamental but I can't see what it is

Comment: In reply to the Answer
1. Yes, I have that
2. Source of P2_X is "Item (application or page item name)"
     Source Value is  SEARCH_STRING
3. Clear Cache is empty

Answer (score 3):

1. Check the configuration of you button, there must be "&SEARCH_STRING." with a dot.
2. Check the source of the field P2_X.
3. Check the "Clear Cache" field of you button, it must be empty.

Comment: Resolved.  I was using the Button to parse the items but in fact I actually needed to BRANCH to the next page with the items